Absolute value of elements of b=Ax and the minimum singular value of A
For $b=Ax$, is there a way to relate the minimum absolute value of the element of $b$, $\min|b_i|$, and the minimum singular value, $\sigma_{min}$, of $A$?
What I want is something like: $\sigma_{min}$ gives an upper bound of $\min|b_i|$. Is it possible?

hmm, take $A$ to be a diagonal matrix with, say, positive entries on its diagonal (which would thus be its singular values). You could construct $x$ which would give a $b$ such that $min |b_i|$ is as small or as large as desired. You could even take $A$ to $\lambda \mathbf{1}$, for some $\lambda > 0$. Unless I misunderstand your question, you could construct a counterexample to your desired statement with diagonal matrices.

Thank you @Malkoun! I see, so there is no way to connect these two quantities together?

First, something is not clear. Are you only taking the minimum over the set of indices $i$? Or are you taking the minimum as $\mathbf{x}$ rangers over $\mathbb{R}^n$ also? This part in your statement is not very clear.

Let us assume that $A$ is a square matrix. Then it can be written as $U \Sigma V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with nonnegative entries, say $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$, which we assume are ordered, i.e. that $\sigma_1 \leq \dots \leq \sigma_n$. Then $\sigma_1 = \operatorname{min}_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \lVert A x \rVert$. Perhaps this is the statement you are looking for?

Hi @Malkoun, thanks for following up! I am taking the element of $b$, the output of $Ax$, that has the minimum absolute value among all the elements in $b$. If there is a relationship between that and $\sigma_1$ of $A$. I understand your point about $\sigma_1 = \min_{||x||=1}||Ax||$ but this is talking about the norm of $b$, not the elements of $b$.

Take $A = \lambda \mathbf{1}$, for some $\lambda > 0$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $b = A x = \lambda x$. You can definitely find some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\operatorname{min} |b_i| = 0$. Indeed, just take $x$ to be any vector with a zero entry somewhere. Moreover, if you take all the entries of $x$ to be equal to some $R > 0$, then if $R$ is sufficiently large, you can make $\operatorname{min} |b_i| = \lambda R$ arbitrarily large. So for this $A$, its smallest singular value is $\lambda$, but $\operatorname{min} |b_i|$ can be anythink in $[0, \infty)$.
